# UNITY - Make a gameobject inactive and active

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, button

I have game objects which is button (Called as tiles), when the button is clicked it will be inactive and there's a condition to be tested if the condition is true the button will be destroyed but if its false the button will back to its active status.

**My game Manager script (The condition):**

```
public void checkword()
 {
     wordBuilded = displayer.text.ToString();

     if (txtContents.Contains(wordBuilded))
     {
         Debug.Log(wordBuilded + " Is on the list");
         wordScore++;
         Debug.Log(wordScore);
     }
     else
     {        
         Debug.Log("Someting is wrong..");
         FindObjectOfType<LetterTiles>().tileStatus();
     }

 }
```

**On my Button (Tile) script (Script attached to the buttons):**

```
public void letterClick()
 {
     gameManager.currentWord += letter;
     gameObject.SetActive(false);

 }

 public void tileStatus()
 {
    gameObject.SetActive(true);
 }
```

Comment: you didn't mention what the problem is

Comment: I want the button object to re appear when the condition is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an object is deactivated Unity won't find it using `FindObjectOfType`.

either keep a local reference to the object [the button] in the game manager before you disable it or hide the button in a different way.

Since you are using a Button, you can use the `interactable` property of the button to make it disabled [and if you want it to be hidden then change the disabled color to transparent] like:

`gameobject.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;`

Comment: Thanks for your answers but how will I put a local reference of the object if I'm using an array for that object?

Comment: loop through the array and compare with name and place it locally , ofc it can be saved many other ways also .

Comment: @MunggoLloyd if you have the objects ready when the game starts, you can find all objects of the type `LetterTiles` and save them in a list. I'd use the interactable trick instead of the deactivating the buttons though.
If you still need to deactivate the game object comment again and I'll edit my answer to include a how to sample to do it.

Comment: Hi @Jimmar I fixed it already with using Interactable and changing the color as you said thank you very much for helping me. But I have a new problem maybe you can help me out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516024/how-to-instantiate-a-game-object-at-the-same-position-where-the-previous-is-dest